# Laravel 5.5 altering pagination for an item to be treated as 2 pages

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I'm trying to change the way an image is displayed when it is being paginated. Normally the images are in portrait mode and i have the perPage set to 2 (so its 2 images per page so it looks like a book), but then there are landscape images that end up being mixed with the portrait ones. All the images have a width and height column to identify if its landscape or portrait.

I want to be able to tell the paginator to treat all the items that are landscape to be called as a 2 pages rather than a single page.

this is my current code:

```
/**
 * The attributes on which the comic list can be ordered
 * @var array
 */
public static $allowedSortingOptions = [
    'sort_order desc'  => 'Sort Order (descending)',
    'random' => 'Random'
];

/**
 * Lists images for the front end
 *
 * @param        $query
 * @param  array $options Display options
 *
 * @return File
 */
public function scopeListFrontEnd($query, $options)
{
    /*
     * Default options
     */
    extract(array_merge([
        'page'       => 1,
        'perPage'    => 1,
        'sort'       => 'sort_order',
        'chapter'    => null,
        'language'   => 'en'
    ], $options)); 

    if($chapter) {
      $query->where('attachment_id', $chapter);
    }

    $query->where('language', $language);

    /*
     * Sorting
     */
    if (!is_array($sort)) {
        $sort = [$sort];
    }

    foreach ($sort as $_sort) {

        if (in_array($_sort, array_keys(self::$allowedSortingOptions))) {
            $parts = explode(' ', $_sort);
            if (count($parts) < 2) {
                array_push($parts, 'desc');
            }
            list($sortField, $sortDirection) = $parts;
            if ($sortField == 'random') {
                $sortField = Db::raw('RAND()');
            }
            $query->orderBy($sortField, $sortDirection);
        }
    }

    $images = $query->paginate($perPage, $page);

    return $images;
}
```

**Edit Clearer:** 
A Landscape image is the equivalent of 2 pages. I want to be able to tell the paginator to treat it as such when i have `$perPage` set to 2 items per page. That way it wont be showing both a landscape image and a portrait image, just the landscape for that page.

Comment: you mean if the image is landscape, you want to show 1 image per page ? what happen if the image potrait and landscape in the same image ?? 1 page each ?

Comment: @punk73 what i mean is that a landscape image is the equivalent of 2 pages. I want to be able to tell the paginator to treat it as such when i have `$perPage` set to 2 items per page. That way it wont be showing both a landscape image and a portrait image, just the landscape for that page.

Comment: i mean is that a landscape image is the equivalent of 2 pages.  --> you want to display one picture in 2 pages ?? 0.5 each ??

Comment: I want to be able to tell the paginator to treat it as such when i have $perPage set to 2 items per page. --> it's mean you display 2 landscapte pictures in one page right ?

Comment: no, its 1 landscape picture displayed as 2 pages. Portrait pictures will display as 1 page and will be grouped together with another portrait image to make 2 pages

Answer (score -1):

```
if($chapter) {
  $query->where('attachment_id', $chapter);
}

$query->where('language', $language);

$limit = 20;
$query->pagination($limit);
```